# Complex Numbers Arithmetic Properties of Conjugate and Modulus Question

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I'm a university student and we have just started studying complex numbers. I have tried to do both the questions and included my working for (a) below, but I am still slightly unclear with the rules of complex numbers. (Also I am new to stackexchange and am still trying to understand the MathJax, so I apologize for the inconvenience).

(a) Find, with proof, all complex numbers w and z such that w = 1 + z and |w| = |z| = 1.

(b) Prove that, for all complex numbers z and w, |z+iw| = |z−iw| if and only if zw ∈ R.

(a) w can be written as:
¯=(1+)(1+⎯⎯⎯)
⟹+⎯⎯⎯+1=0,
and ||=1 means ⎯⎯⎯=1,
so there’s a quadratic equation for

Comment: Hello and a warm welcome to stackexchange!  A basic math jax guide can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you can have it enabled in your text by enclosing text in two dollars

Comment: Cf. [this deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3931260/complex-numbers-proof-questions)

Comment: When working with complex numbers, especially in the beginning, it can be helpful to draw rough diagrams. Eg, for part (a), $z$ and $w$ are on the unit circle. Carefully check the question for part (b), because what you've written is incorrect. $|z+iw| = |z-iw|$ iff $z/w$ is real (or trivially, if $w=0$).